# how to remove all text before a pattern?

Tags: r, regex

Consider this simple example

```
text = c('hello guys this is it START hi',
         'one two START this is good',
         'a longer example. I cannot believe it! START hello')
```

I am trying to write a regex that will remove all text before the `START` token. So output will be

```
text = c('START hi',
         'START this is good',
         'START hello')
```

I tried to use `stringr::str_replace_all()` but I am not sure what the right `regex` should be.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Use `^.+?(?=START)` if you tried `stringr::str_replace_all()`. Or, `"^.+?(?=\\bSTART\\b)"`

Comment: `sub(".*(\\<START\\>.*$)", "\\1", text)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem you can use a positive lookahead `'.*(?=START)'`, as follows:

```
# load environment
library(stringr)
# create text vector
text = c('hello guys this is it START hi',
         'one two START this is good',
         'a longer example. I cannot believe it! START hello')
# remove pattern
text = str_remove(text, '.*(?=START)')
# print output
print(text)
```

Here is the output:

```
[1] "START hi"           "START this is good" "START hello"
```

Comment: of course! lookahead.... thanks!

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Watch out, if you have two or more `START`s, this `.*` will make it match all text up to the last occurrence.

Comment: you're right, in this case you should use `.?` instead of `.*` (`*` stands for greedy search, while `?` stands for lazy search).. thanks for sharing, mate!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the heads up!